# How to get author name as a pure string text and not the macro itself

Tags: citing, strings, text

I need to access to author names as pure text strings to be able to analyze them with tools such as those of the xstrings package. For instance, the small LaTeX program (testciteauthor.tex) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xstring}
\addbibresource{testciteauthor.bib}
\begin{filecontents*}{testciteauthor.bib}
@book{Knu86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\citeauthor{Knu86}\par
\StrLen{\citeauthor{Knu86}}\par
\StrLen{1234567890}\par
\end{document}
```

When executed gives :

```
Knuth
2
10
```

Showing that the second line, *\StrLen{\citeauthor{Knu86}}*, does not give what I expected, 4, (obviously).
So, knowing that I know a bit of LaTeX but almost nothing of TeX, I have desperately searched the web for a solution, but without success. 
Do you have any idea ?
Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The author is not a simple string in `biblatex`, but a list structure. If we understand better what the end goal is, there might be better ways to achieve it.

Comment: I want to add several href links. But, none command from biblatex is able to do a such complex work. This is why I have started to develop my own unique \CITE command to do that. But I stumble on the problem to get the author name, whatever it could be, to build some sort of "dictionary" (as in python) with the possibility to store additional information, since \citeauthor{key} is  a macro and does not returns a string ! For that, I need the "author(s)" name(s) as a pure string to be able to manage dictionary keys.

Comment: This sounds like something that should be done using `biblatex` itself. If you can edit your question with a specific thing that you want your new cite command to do, it can probably be done. Turning an author name into a string is likely not the way to do this.

Comment: There is no sufficient place to do that in a Comment. But I can show you an example for a citation, in text, as I want : [authorA, 7, P2, U3; 12, U11 | AuthorB, 43, U56 | etc], where 7 is a link to the citation number in the References, P2 is a link to a PDF file, U3 a link to a web site, and so on. For a single author or a single citation I already know of how to do that. But for one citation with several authors and/or for some with multiple citations for one author, I need the author names to compact information. This will be very useful for my work.

Comment: Right, that's why I said edit your question!

Comment: @Alan : I have to think about all this and try more tests. However, my primary question was not so difficult to understand : does somebody know  a way to modify the actual \citeauthor command to return the author name as a pure text string ? I am confident that the answers to this question will be helpful to those who wish to create their own, say, \MCITE command.

Comment: Now I think we're going around in circles. I would say, knowing a reasonable amount about how the `biblatex` code works, that this is *not* likely to be a viable approach. But you're welcome to delve into the code yourself to figure out how to do it your way.